# Getting minimum distance of points with scalable algorithm

Tags: distance, coordinates, algorithm

I have a number of geographical coordinates with latitudes/longitudes:

```
id  | name          | lat       | lon 
1   | New York      | 40.730610 |  74.0060
2   | Philadelphia  | 75.1652   | 39.9526
3   | Washington DC | 77.0369   | 38.9072 
... | ...           | ...       | ...
```

I could calculate all distances between my points using standard tools, but I'm *only interested in the minimum distance* of one point to all others. But that would require N*N (N: number points) calculations and is too slow.

A heuristic/approximate approach would be better.

Any ideas?

Comment: Will you need a practical solution as well, or you just looking for a theory comprehension? Which software are you willing/you can use?

Comment: Ideally we'll get it to run in Excel even. 

But it's more important for me to find a faster approach than trying all options.

Comment: ok. So, IMHO if you want a pure Excel solution I suggest asking this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). Otherwise, I am kindly asking you to change  Excel in your question to any library/software/tool that works with geographic/spatial data and more important that you have access to/you are willing to use. Hense, your question won't be marked as *off-topic*. Personally, I can suggest a solution using QGIS, but I am not sure if it suits your requirements.